# LVM not booting after VM migration from KVM to VMWare

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, lvm

I've migrated a VM from an old system based on Centos and KVM.
The VM itself is also based on Centos.
The VM had 4 disks in it and those are still being kept, everything was basically converted.

The problem I am facing is that after all the disk converstions and everything being recognized by VMWare, when I try to boot the system, it stalls without even prompting for any OS start. My guess is that it is not reading LVM or for some reason LVM is not being activated.
I am kind of blind in here as I don't know what else to look.
I have also tried a Centos recovery session, where I can see all the volumes and data inside, only after running the "vgchange -a y" command.

Is there someone who could point me to some other direction? I did this type of conversion before but the VM had only one disk, so that was "easy".

Comment: you need to check if the device names in kvm was vdX and now using vmware you have sda

Comment: Well, that was not the case, I guess. I decided to redo everything as someone did started the old machine while I was creating a backup of the disk files, so, the consistency wasn't already not good. Also, I found that all of the disk files were using qcow2 format (which were not the case based on the file extension), which I wasn't aware and I was using default settings for qemu-img to convert.I am redoing everything now, so that I can get it right. If there is anything else, I will post here again.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Nah.. still the same problem.
So basically, I can convert all the disk files from KVM to VMDK format. That works.
I can boot on a rescue Centos CD and see the volumes. That is fine.

The problem remains when I try to boot from the system itself. It just hangs there without any action only with a prompt blinking.
My guess is that grub is not loading correctly for some reason.

Here is what I've tried so far:
- FSCK to volumes to fix any possible inconsistencies.
- Reinstall grub to /dev/sda
- rebuild initramfs with dracut command

Anything I should look as well?

Comment: I kind of solved it. I did the conversion using a different method and now I am able to get the VMs to boot ... after 30 to 40 minutes looking at the frozen prompt. Any guess on what could be the reason?